# prevent a program from automatically opening on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Whenever I plug in a USB device that happens to have jpeg files on it into my Ubuntu system, a photo album program automatically opens.  How do I prevent this?  I would prefer if a file manager window would open or even if nothing would happen.

Answer (score 2):

In nautilus, Edit -> Preferences, then the media tab. At the bottom, uncheck "Browse media when inserted." There are other settings in this window that control how programs and devices behave on your system.